# how we can use vtiger crm mobile api[vtigercrm/modules/Mobile/api/ws]?

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

How we can use vtiger crm existing api mobile api, please let me know with example ,also dont suggest me for vtwsclib-1.4.

I want to use vtigercrm/modules/Mobile/api/ws.
Help me please.

Comment: You want to use Mobile Module or Only API?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use vtwsclib-1.4 with the "Mobile" API.

I was in the same situation as you, so I started documenting the `Mobile` API myself.

I shared the current status of my findings on this GitHub page: http://gixworks.github.io/vtiger-mobile-client-ios/